# The matrix $M$ is $10 \times 10$ with unit upper triangular and zero everywhere else. How to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors please?

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix $M$ is $10 \times 10$ with unit upper triangular and zero everywhere else. How to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors please?

It is easy to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors when $M$ is only $3 \times 3$, while calculating in the case that $M$ is $10 \times 10$ involves too much calculation. Is there a smart way to do so?

Comment: Characteristic polynomial is ??  (determinant of an upper triangular matrix is easy) Therefore eigenvalues are ??

Comment: If you apply $M$ to the vector $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{10})^{T}$ you get $(x_2,x_3,...,x_9,0)^T$. Then $(x_2,x_3,...,x_{10},0)^T=r(x_1,x_2,...,x_{10})^{T}$ tells you that $r_2=rx_1, x_3=r^2x_1,...,x_{10}=r^9x_1, 0=r^{10}x_1$. If $r\neq0$ then $x_1=x_2=...=x_{10}=0$. So, the only eigenvalue is $r=0$. In which case $x_2=x_3=...=x_{10}=0$ and $x_1\neq0$ give the corresponding eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a matrix that has $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue, and $a,b$ are scalars, then $aA+bI$ has $a\lambda + b$ as an eigenvalue. To see this, note that if $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then $(aA+bI)\mathbf{x} = a(A\mathbf{x})+b\mathbf{x} = a\lambda\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{x} = (a\lambda + b)\mathbf{x}$.

If $B$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix, then its only eigenvalue is $0$.

Now, your matrix $A$ is such that it can be written as $N+I$, where $I$ is the identity and $N$ is strictly upper triangular. So its only eigenvalue is $1$ (with multiplicity $10$). To find all its eigenvectors, find the nullspace of $N$.